# Install a specific Neo4j version Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j

I have a project running using embedded Neo4j.2.0.1 with Spring 3.2.8 and SDN 3.0.2 on my dev environment (windows).

I want to deploy it on an integration environment (Ubuntu).

Installing the latest version of Neo4j (2.2.1) is giving errors at startup.

I can't find anywhere on internet how to install a **specific version of Neo4j** (an older version) on Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you starting Neo4j 2.2.1 with your graph database files from your dev environment? If so, have you explicitly upgraded your them by setting `allow_store_upgrade=true` in `.\conf\neo4j.properties`?

Comment: Assuming you want the community version, behind this link you can find packages for all OSs, all versions.   http://neo4j.com/download/other-releases/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think the problem comes from the db version itself but with the versions of Spring-data-neo4j, Spring and Spring Security. I can't find any versions combo with which the program starts fine. And for your first question, No I'm using a new datastore.

Comment: Well, keeping the same Spring versions, It works fine with 2.0.4.
Thanks for your help

Comment: In case you're using the debian packages, there is a technique called apt-pinning to force a specific version of a given package, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto.